# Fail to resume after hibernate on Ubuntu 21.04

Tags: hibernate

I have a Ubuntu 21.04 laptop with hibernate enabled. It has worked flawlessly until a few days ago, then it stopped working likely after installing and updating some packages, including a new kernel image.

Now each time I try to resume after hibernate, it falls back to restart.
On dmesg log I read the following lines:

```
[   17.407048] kernel: PM: hibernation: resume from hibernation
[   17.409714] kernel: PM: hibernation: Marking nosave pages: [mem 0x00000000-0x00000fff]
[   17.409717] kernel: PM: hibernation: Marking nosave pages: [mem 0x0004f000-0x0004ffff]
[   17.409718] kernel: PM: hibernation: Marking nosave pages: [mem 0x0009e000-0x000fffff]
[   17.409721] kernel: PM: hibernation: Marking nosave pages: [mem 0xae6e9000-0xae6effff]
[   17.409723] kernel: PM: hibernation: Marking nosave pages: [mem 0xaf0cd000-0xaf5abfff]
[   17.409744] kernel: PM: hibernation: Marking nosave pages: [mem 0xb1e4c000-0xb1ed3fff]
[   17.409747] kernel: PM: hibernation: Marking nosave pages: [mem 0xb2698000-0xb2698fff]
[   17.409748] kernel: PM: hibernation: Marking nosave pages: [mem 0xb54af000-0xb54affff]
[   17.409749] kernel: PM: hibernation: Marking nosave pages: [mem 0xb54d8000-0xb54d8fff]
[   17.409751] kernel: PM: hibernation: Marking nosave pages: [mem 0xb7db3000-0xb7ffffff]
[   17.409761] kernel: PM: hibernation: Marking nosave pages: [mem 0xb8759000-0xb87fffff]
[   17.409765] kernel: PM: hibernation: Marking nosave pages: [mem 0xb8f9d000-0xb8ffffff]
[   17.409767] kernel: PM: hibernation: Marking nosave pages: [mem 0xba6f5000-0xba7fffff]
[   17.409773] kernel: PM: hibernation: Marking nosave pages: [mem 0xbbcec000-0xffffffff]
[   17.410626] kernel: PM: hibernation: Basic memory bitmaps created
[   17.481616] kernel: PM: Using 3 thread(s) for decompression
[   17.481620] kernel: PM: Loading and decompressing image data (835177 pages)...
[   17.481626] kernel: PM: hibernation: Image mismatch: architecture specific data
[   17.481627] kernel: PM: hibernation: Read 3340708 kbytes in 0.01 seconds (334070.80 MB/s)
[   17.482589] kernel: PM: Error -1 resuming
[   17.482594] kernel: PM: hibernation: Failed to load image, recovering.
[   17.482992] kernel: PM: hibernation: Basic memory bitmaps freed
[   17.483572] kernel: PM: hibernation: resume failed (-1)
```

Here is my configuration:

```
$ cat /sys/power/state
freeze mem disk
$ cat /sys/power/disk
[platform] shutdown reboot suspend test_resume
$ cat /proc/cmdline 
BOOT_IMAGE=/vmlinuz-5.11.0-25-generic root=/dev/mapper/vgubuntu-root ro quiet splash resume=UUID=a2be2098-*********-c2b3b22def13 mem_sleep_default=deep
```

Any idea of what might be wrong?

Comment: There's a [new kernel bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1925843) that might be at fault. Try booting with an older kernel to see if you still have the problem.

Comment: I'm now using the 5.11.0-26.28 kernel in proposed and the bug does not occur anymore.

Comment: — Thank you for letting us know. I don't have that version available in my proposed, but I do have 5.11.0-27, which I installed. It was a mess, including the suspend. So, I'll wait until the non-proposed updates come through.